# NiceScroll doesn't work after AJAX loading

Tags: jquery, ajax, scroll

I have a problem with Nice Scroll. It works fine, but when I load AJAX images it doesn't work. Interestingly, when I resize the window, open Firebug or whatever, it starts to work.

What can I do to do this automatically?

I tried:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("window").trigger('resize');
}, 0);
```

After the AJAX loading function, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Most likely, yOu are initializing nice scroll before the Ajax request completes. Try to initialize nice scroll in the success event handler of the Ajax request.

Comment: The problem is that when I go to home page (where Ajax is loaded) and it works, but when I go to static page (like contact) and then I click to menu item which load ajax, then it doesn't work to the moment when I change size of the window.

Comment: Is that possible to include your code into a fiddle for us to look?

Comment: Unfortunately not ;/  I need a function that does something corresponding to manually resize the window, because then scrollbar starts to work.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not much anyone can do, without your code or a demo page, other than make a guess.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When content on your div changes you need to call nicescroll resize method.

```
$("your-div-name").getNiceScroll().resize()
```

Keep in mind if image size is not set in img tag, you need to call resize when all images are fully loaded.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to InuYaksa's answer If you have no access on the implementation, you can just implement the mouseover function on the content wrapper as a workaround.

```
// Call resize whenever mouse
$("#scroll-area").mouseover(function() {
  $("#scroll-area").getNiceScroll().resize();
});
```

from: http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2013/05/07/jquery-nicescroll-plugin-doesnt-work-for-dynamic-content/

**Improved mouseover solution**

```
//in the case of scrolling content loaded via AJAX
    $(document).on('mouseover','#scroll-area', function () {
       $(this).getNiceScroll().resize();
    });
```

**Using viewport/wrap**

```
$(document).on('mouseover','#scroll-wrap', function () {

    var widget_wrap=$(this);
    var widget_viewport=$(this).parent();

    widget_viewport.getNiceScroll(widget_wrap).resize();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please you must use the below code to resolve your problem. It works fine with ajax load.

```
$("MYSCROLLCONTAINERS").getNiceScroll().remove();
$("div[id^='ascrail']").remove();
jQuery("MYSCROLLCONTAINERS").niceScroll({
                autohidemode:false
            });
```

This worked for me.